# Index out of range appears sometimes and disappears when i run again python

Tags: python

```
import numpy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import serial

V=[]
I=[]
P=[]
count=0
arduinoData=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600) # importing serial data

a=input('enter the no of observation required = ') # user choice to get the required no of observations

while count<a:
    count=count+1
    while(arduinoData.inWaiting()==0):
        pass
    arduinoString=arduinoData.readline()
    data=arduinoString.split(",")
    voltage = float(data[0])
    current = float(data[1])
    power   = float(data[2])
    V.append(voltage)
    I.append(current)
    P.append(power)
    print V,",",I,",",P
#plt.plot(V)`enter code here`
#plt.show()
#plt.ylim([150])
```

I get this error off and on sometimes the code works fine and sometimes index is out of range i'm really confused why is it so
I have just started learning python programming

Comment: You are splitting a string from a CSV file.  Are you sure that there are always 3 values for each row?  If not `data[0]`, `data[1]`, or `data[2]` could fail.

Comment: the data through the serial port is always 3 in a row i viewed it on the serial monitor of the arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the string to make sure it has three comma separated elements?  If it doesn't you may need to treat it as malformed and throw it away.

Comment: Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(a);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(b);

Comment: Try printing string and see what state of it is when it fails.

Comment: ['23', '115.00\r\n']
['23', '10.00', '15.00\r\n']

Comment: this is the result

Comment: First string only has two elements.

Comment: sometimes due to delay in arduino it shows only 2 values and sometimes all 3 in python but in arduino serial monitor all 3 values are printed but why is it so i think the issue is in the serial data right ...?